# jQuery, clone element and replace part of its name

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a little script that copies rows of a table and appends the new row to the end of the table. But each cells contain an element that have a name like "Details[0].Amount". When I clone a row, I just want to set its name just by increment the index part of the old one like "Details[1].Amount". Here is my code:

```
var clonedRow = $('#body tr:first').clone();
clonedRow.find('input').val(''); //set its name
$('#body').append(clonedRow);
```

Comment: please share html table in you post to understand the table structure

Comment: Sorry, but why do you need to know the table structure? I just want to copy an element that has a name like "Details[0].XXX" and set the new element's name like "Details[1].XXX".

Comment: I see you are new here. Please read about [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), to understand why you need to provide a ***minimal and verifiable version*** of your table structure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the input's `name` property either directly or by jQuery's [`prop()`](https://api.jquery.com/prop) method.

```
var index = 1; //do whatever you need to determine the correct index
//uses template literal to build the name
clonedRow.find('input').prop('name',`Details[${index}].Amount`);
```

To do the actual replace, depending on the structure of the names, you could simply use a regex replace (\d matches digits)

```
newName = oldName.replace(/\d/,index);
```

More sophisticated code would obviously need to be used in case of more complex names.

Demo

```js
jQuery('button').click(()=>{
  var clone = $('table tr:first').clone();
  var index = $('table tr').length;
  var input = clone.find('input');
  var oldName = input.prop('name');
  //replace the first number occurance with index
  var newName = oldName.replace(/\d/,index);
  input.prop('name',newName).val(newName);
  $('table').append(clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A Row</td>
    <td><input name="Details[0].Amount" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Clone</button>
```

Comment: Going to need to parse existing namees since *"each cells contain an element that have a name"*

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem is the elements' names are like "Details[0]...". The ending parts are different. I just want to replace index part of a name by keeping rest of same.

Comment: @TamerlanRustambayli see edit, added the replacement part of the answer.

Comment: @PatrickEvans, with a little changes it worked perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#replace()` inside `prop(propname,function)` or `attr(attrName,function)`

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  var clone = $('table tr:first').clone();
  var index = $('table tr').length;
  clone.find('input').prop('name', function(_, curr) {
    return curr.replace(/\d+/, index);
  })
   // set value as name just for demo
  .val(function() {
    return this.name
  });

  $('table').append(clone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>        
    <td><input name="Details[0].Amount" /></td>
    <td><input name="Details[0].Foo" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button>Clone</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

am  not a js expert but i guess one possible solution would be using regular expressions using some approach like this

```
var val ="Details[0].Amount";
val=val.replace(/\d+/,function(elm){return (parseInt(elm))+1});
```